# Radio button Values do not exist on type element

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

Hi I am just trying to grab the values from a couple radio buttons on a component in an Angular project I am working on. If I put the same offending code..

```
this.format = document.querySelector('input[name="case"]:checked').value;
```

...in the if statement in a console log it doesn't throw an error.  Also, when I reload vs code sometimes the error isn't thrown either and it works perfectly.

So can anyone see why I am getting this error?  Thanks for your help. Please let me know if you need more info.

```
'file:////src/app/input-format2.directive.ts'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.'
at: '15,72'
source: 'ts'
code: '2339'
```

This is the directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputFormat2]'
})
export class InputFormat2Directive {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('appInputFormat2') format;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur() {
    const value: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    this.format = document.querySelector('input[name="case"]:checked').value;
    if (this.format === 'lowercase') {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = value.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

And the html:

```
  Custom directive where case is determined by user
  <b>upon loss of focus</b> (clean approach):
</div>
<input type="radio" name='case' value="lowercase">lowercase
<br>
<input type="radio" name='case' value="uppercase">UPPERCASE
<br>
<input type="text" submit="submit" [appInputFormat2]="'lowercase'">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a typescript error. By default document.querySelector return Element instance which doesn't have an input value.

You have to "cast" it :

```
this.format = (<HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('input[name="case"]:checked')).value;
```

Comment: Ahhhhh it's called 'cast'! Okay thank you for your explanation

Comment: Any idea why it was throwing me this error sporadically and not every single time I tried to render?

Comment: While that will work for this example, the type is wrong. The correct type for radio buttons (and check boxes) is `HTMLOptionElement`, not `HTMLInputElement`.

Answer (score 3):

While using `document.querySelector`, if you don't specify for the target element's type, typescript will consider it as `Element` by default.

You can specify the type by the below way:

```
this.format = (document.querySelector('input[name="case"]:checked') as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I need to level up my typescript skillz. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pierre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48701169/3760848) as a starting point, the better way to do it is:

```js
this.format = (document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('input[name="case"]:checked')).value;
```

since `querySelector` uses [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types).